# Strange div behaviour in Chrome and Camino, but not in Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-float

I made a site (and now it looks terrible due to all the awful colors, but those are just for me to see where my divs are in this stadium of positioning) with a very basic layout, it can be found [here](http://korilu.nl/maurits/iets.html).

Now my problem is that when I was at school and visited my site using chrome on a Windows machine, it looked fine. The `div#side` was next to the `div#content`, but when I visited my site at home, where I am now, on a Mac machine using Chrome too, the div started moving...
The first time I loaded the page it looked fine. The second time I loaded the page it moved down for the height of the `div#content`, but still on the right side of the page. And it changed per pageload, it was down there time 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.

On Camino (still on the mac machine) it went down there every time, it didn't move...

On safari, it behaves exactly as I want, image found [here](http://korilu.nl/maurits/iets.tiff). It is a .tiff image, I hope you all can view it...

Now the question is: how do I get the page as shown in the image cross-browser?

PS
The font in the image is just the result of me playing with safari preferences and changing the default font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your side bar is 25% width and your content is 75%. Then your `.vr` is 1px, so your total width is 100% + 1. The sidebar (the last element) doesn't fit into the width that's left (it's 1px too big).

There are a number of ways to solve that problem. Try changing up your width slightly or handling the vr a little differently. You could use the faux columns method described here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: Wow, that's really strange, because that was the first and only thing I could think of, and tried reducing `div#side`'s width to 24%, but that didn't work, leaving me completely clueless! And now it does!